# Manipulate XML XDocument XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I need to be able to manipulate a XML with a schema like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<SOAP-ENVELOPE:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENVELOPE='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<SOAP-ENVELOPE:Header>
    <Authorization>
        <FromURI/>
        <User/>
        <Password/>
        <TimeStamp/>
    </Authorization>
    <Notification>
        <NotificationURL/>
        <NotificationExpiration/>
        <NotificationID/>
        <MustNotify/>
    </Notification>
</SOAP-ENVELOPE:Header>
<SOAP-ENVELOPE:Body SOAP-ENVELOPE:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
</SOAP-ENVELOPE:Body>
```

I need to add the data for FromURI, User, Password, NotificiationURL, MustNotify, etc and within the body I sill need to add dynamically:

```
<SOAPSDK4:APIOperation xmlns:SOAPSDK4="http://www.someserver.com/message/">
</SOAPSDK4:APIOperation>
```

To finally construct the structure within APIOperation that is needed for the web service but can be easily done using XDocument to create a tree.

I've been having troubles to find information for a week on how to manipulate data within the envelope and here I need to do so with tree different levels.

Comment: So as you say, construction using XDocument is easy. Where are you having problems?

Comment: I am having troubles adding data to the header section to each element.
Then I need to be able to create any quantity of items with it's structure within the APIOperation section, I am not entirely sure how to do that using XDocument, that's why I am creating piece by piece with XmlDocument for now.

Comment: "I am having trouble" isn't at all clear. If you could give more details, we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
XNamespace envNs = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
var fromUri = doc.Root
       .Element(envNs + "Header")
       .Element("Authorization")
       .Element("FromURI");
fromUri.Value = "http://trst";
doc.Save(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I decided to create it from scratch using XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument Request = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration declarationRequest = Request.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");
Request.InsertBefore(declaracionRequest, Request.DocumentElement);
XmlElement soapEnvelope = Request.CreateElement("SOAP-ENVELOPE", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
Request.AppendChild(soapEnvelope);
XmlElement soapHeader = Request.CreateElement("SOAP-ENVELOPE", "Header", Request.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
Request.DocumentElement.AppendChild(soapHeader);
XmlElement soapBody = Request.CreateElement("SOAP-ENVELOPE", "Body", Request.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
soapBody.SetAttribute("SOAP-ENVELOPE:encodingStyle", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
Request.DocumentElement.AppendChild(soapBody);
XmlElement nodeAutorization = Request.CreateElement("Authorization");
XmlElement nodeFromURI = Request.CreateElement("FromURI");
...
soapHeader.AppendChild(nodoAutorization);
nodeAutorization.AppendChild(nodoFromURI);
nodeAutorization.AppendChild(nodoUser);
...
```

And in the same way everything else. The problem is, the code gets pretty large using all the elements and kind of difficult to generate many nodes at the same level.

I do not know if there are better practices or something easier but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could just use a `StringBuilder` to create the SOAP envelope, and then convert that string to a `XDocument`.